How to combine params and inline code in Quarto
In Quarto we can use R inline code and parameters from the YAML. I would like to combine them. Here is a reproducible example to combine inline code and parameters from the YAML:
---
title: "Params in inline code"
format: html
params:
  alpha: 2
---
       
This value is `{r} params$alpha`

Output:

Apparently this doesn't work. The parameters value doesn't show in the inline code of the document. The parameters does work in a code chunk, but I would like to use this in a inline code to keep the document clean. So I was wondering if anyone knows how to combine parameters and inline code like above in a Quarto document?

For params to work you need to explicitly set the engine to knitr like this
---
title: "Untitled"
format: html
params:
  alpha: 2
engine: knitr
---

## Params inline code 

This values is `r params$alpha` 





Just add engine information in the configuration part.
The code is:
---
title: "test"
format: html
engine: knitr
params:
  alpha: 2
---

## Quarto  


the parameter is `r params$alpha`

